# Is there a way to generate two different text files on the fly with php?

Tags: php, file, text, on-the-fly

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856761/php-file-creation-and-download-on-the-fly) topic I'm able to generate one single text file and download it on the fly. But I would like to generate two separated text files. My code seems like this:

```
        $status = //math

        if(status)

           header("Content-type: text/plain");
           header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=config.txt");

 //...config text

 include 'test.php';
```

Test.php file:

```
<?php 

    $timeout = "time";

    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=timout.xml");

    echo $timeout;
?>
```

the timeout.xml text is being included inside config.txt, generating only the timout.xml file to download. Is there a way to generate two separated text files to download on the fly?

Comment: Not within the same request, no. You'll have to make two separate download requests.

Comment: @deceze I thought I could do including another php file, that was my idea, so how may I call two different requests? considering I'm using only one button is it possible?

Comment: You could do this if you generated the two files and put them in a tarball/zip file and output that instead

Comment: @VictorOliveira a request against the server is meant to return a single file (normally HTML or JSON or something like that), but you can alternatively return a different file, but the rule is you can only return one file for one request. That's how REST works.

Comment: @Brian zips not really an option, but I read about this few minutes ago; thanks

Comment: Think about what that would look like in the browser, it doesn't care that you `include` some file server-side. You can't receive two files with a click on one link. You could trigger two downloads via Javascript if you wanted.

Comment: @deceze could u post some code to guide me? thus I could accept as an answer

Comment: What @deceze said is a viable alternative to you for sure. You could use JS on a link to trigger two different requests to the server, which would let you technically trigger two downloads off a single click, but it would still execute **two PHP scripts** on the server side, or the single one with two different sets of request variables.

Comment: might be you can get some help from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993468/php-header-to-download-multiple-files-in-loop/19972789#19972789

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do it because HTTP doesnt support the downloading of multiple files in a single click..The best option would be zipping the files on the server and transfering it as said [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993468/php-header-to-download-multiple-files-in-loop/19972789#19972789)

Or you can use javascript to on the link to request two request to the server and which lets you fetch the data from the single click as @deceze and @brian said in the comment